# Search for questions that match certain criteria

Tags: support, search

I'd like to search for questions with badge "sql", no accepted answer, and order the results by the age of the question.  Is it possible to search like that from the browser address bar?  Or in any other way?

How about other criteria, like "no answer at all", "no upvote", or even "less than 100 views"?

(Apologies if this is a dumb question. I can't seem to find the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the [Ninja search options](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=).

For your sql results use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]%20hasaccepted%3a0&tab=newest):

> [**[sql]** hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]%20hasaccepted%3a0&tab=newest)

Comment: Thanks. If anyone else wonders about the encoding in the second link, it's stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql] hasaccepted:0&tab=newest